# Changing the values of a table when running SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to change the values of a table column only for the SQL statement.

Lets say I have a table with the columns Name, Points, and Country. I'd like to change the names from what ever value there might be to 1, 2, 3, ... (e.g. Peter = 1, Mike = 2, Lisa = 3). The query should automatically assign values to the names as I don't know how many names there are for each country.

I did some research and only found this CASE solution. However, I would like to change all values of this column when running the SQL query without having to add each name to the CASE statement.

```
SELECT Name, Points, Country
  CASE Name
    WHEN "Peter" THEN "1"
    ELSE Name
  END,
FROM ...
```

Note: the names are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If you don't care which numbers are assigned to which name, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select Name, Points, Country,
       dense_rank() over (order by Name) as name_int
from . . .
```

Comment: that's a perfect solution for my case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Points, Country,
 Case when Name REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]' then  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()
 ELSE name
 END AS Name
FROM table;
```

Comment: To make this answer more useful to readers of this question, consider adding a description to explain what you're doing and why your doing it.